# Change string in select option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in html document.

I want to replace "pikusadrian" with "Adrian Pikus"

Why does my script not work?

```js
var text = document.getElementById("user").innerHTML;
if (text == "pikusadrian") {
  document.getElementById("user").textContent = "Adrian Pikus";
}
```

```html
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="operator" placeholder="operator" required />
<option selected><span id="user">pikusadrian</span></option>
```

Comment: because your HTML is invalid - options cannot have spans

Comment: `<option selected id="user">...</option>` and then `document.getElementById('user').text = ...;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invalid HTML - you close the select and have invalid spans in the options

This works

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("#operator option")].forEach(opt => {
  if (opt.text == "pikusadrian") opt.text = "Adrian Pikus";
})
```

```html
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="operator" id="operator" placeholder="operator" required>
  <option selected>pikusadrian</option>
</select>
```

This MIGHT work, but normally options do not have IDs

```js
const opt = document.getElementById("user");
if (opt.text === "pikusadrian") opt.text = "Adrian Pikus";
```

```html
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="operator" id="operator" placeholder="operator" required>
  <option selected id="user">pikusadrian</option>
</select>
```